# Forcing CNN filters to look at non adjacent data combinations

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

So basically I am building a conv net, but I am not using images per say. I am using the time curves of multiple properties in the data that I made into a 2D array. this means while the first index of the array is important and correlates to the time index of that data, the order within these arrays does not matter so long as they are consistent.

I want my CNN to look at all combinations of that data, so if i have a row with [1,2,3,4] and my kernel size is 2 then I want the filter to be applied to [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,3], [2,4], [3,4] even though some of the data is not adjacent (I excluded the other dimension here for ease of example).

Is there any way with tensorflow that I can make my convolution layer look at data in that manner? I know for a typical image this wouldn't make sense, but I also know there are plenty of other projects that use convolution networks for non image data.

Comment: The "convolutional" part specifically implies some kind of meaningful distance metric in the axis over which you are applying that type of layer.  What you want to do is to have a layer that is convolutional in time, and fully connected in the various sequences.  This is exactly how a normal convolutional network operates over the rgb channels... those are set up fully connected.  So what you want is a 1D convolution with N channels, however many time series you have.

Comment: Oh my god, I didn't even think of that! thank you so much, I really appreciate it